# How do i change Kubernetes DiskPressure status from true to false?

Tags: kubernetes

After creating a simple nginx deployment, my pod status shows as "PENDING". When I run kubectl get pods command, I get the following:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-6b474476c4-dq26w   0/1     Pending   0          50m
nginx-deployment-6b474476c4-wjblx   0/1     Pending   0          50m
```

If I check on my node health with `kubectl describe node`, I get:

```
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  kubernetes-master
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:43:57 +0530
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Wed, 05 Aug 2020 09:12:31 +0530   Wed, 05 Aug 2020 09:12:31 +0530   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:43:36 +0530   Tue, 04 Aug 2020 23:01:43 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         True    Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:43:36 +0530   Tue, 04 Aug 2020 23:02:06 +0530   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:43:36 +0530   Tue, 04 Aug 2020 23:01:43 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Wed, 05 Aug 2020 12:43:36 +0530   Tue, 04 Aug 2020 23:02:06 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
```

Comment: Did you wonder why does it happen? Did you see this [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#node-conditions) ?

Answer (score 8):

You can remove the taint for disk pressure using below command but ideally you need to investigate why kubelet is reporting disk pressure . The node may be out of disk space.

```
kubectl taint nodes <nodename> node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure-
```

This will get you out of pending state of the nginx pods.

Comment: i have already used this command, but it is still not working. can you please provide some other solution?

Comment: Agreed with @manjeet issue is still the same. The control plane will add the taint as soon as you try to remove it. confirmed it from the node spec "timeAdded" of taint.

Answer (score 0):

@manjeet,
What's the out put of 'df -kh' on the node?
Find the disk/partiion/pv that has pressure. Increase it. Then restart kubelet. Then remove the taint. Things should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 kubectl taint nodes <nodename> node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule-
```